# What does 'Minimum Holding Voltage" refer to for a Thermal Fuse?

Tags: voltage, fuses, specifications

One of the components I am looking at for a new design is a thermal fuse. In the documentation it refers to a "Minimum holding voltage". Source: https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/sa.pdf.
Considering it has no electromagnetic components, and it is a fuse so the voltage across it should be very low, does anyone have any idea what the specification could refer to?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a 'fuse' in the sense of a fusible wire link. It's a temperature controlled resistor with a positive temperature coefficient, a PTC, whose resistance varies between very low when cool, very high when hot.

When cool and passing rated load current, the I<sup>2</sup>R heating is low, and it stays in its low resistance 'conducting' state.

When either ambient temperature or load current increases to 'trip' the device, the resistance rises so that it 'disconnects' the load, within a specified leakage current, which is 200 mA on the linked data sheet.

This tripped state is stable, as long as the power supply and load remain connected. Although the I is low, the I<sup>2</sup>R heating is enough, with the much increased R, to keep the device hot.

The 'Minimum Holding Voltage' is the power supply voltage above which the device remains stable in its tripped state. Reduce the power supply voltage below that, and it may cool down to the conducting state. This is how the device is reset to its conducting state, remove the load or the supply for long enough.

Obviously these temperature-related specification depend on heatsinking and ambient temperature, so be careful to understand the rating conditions.

Comment: Hi Neil, If you look at the data sheet, you can see that it is not a variable resistor. There is a PTC material which expands and breaks the connection between the terminals when the temperature is high enough.

Comment: @JohnFahey Their PTC material is constructed so that the contact between grains would be broken at a high enough temperature. In use for overload control, a continued holding or leakage current flows, which negative feedback effectively controls the temperature so the grains are just touching. I'm not sure what your picture of a variable resistance is, perhaps it has a shaft sticking out so you can twiddle it. A PTC presents a variable resistance to the circuit. A fuse or switch changes between m/uohms and G/Tohms, a PTC between ohms and kohms. Modifed answer to clarify my meaning

Comment: The connection is remade when the temperature decreases, and due to the open circuit, no holding current would flow. The term "Minimum Holding Voltage" seems completely nonsensical in this context.

Comment: @JohnFahey Sigh, the device has two modes of operation, pure thermal from overtemperature  that you describe, and current overload, which I major on as it's more complicated.

Comment: @JohnFahey I've just realised anothr reason I majored on the over-current mode, because that's the mode in which the 'minimum holding voltage' that the OP asked about is relevant, this being a Q/A site and all., focusing on the question asked.